# Logitech cordless mouse problem

Tags: mouse

I recently purchased a new Toshiba laptop and a Logitech M510 cordless mouse. I am running Mint 13 on the laptop.

Initially (at least once) the mouse worked fine. Then it ceased to work. I've seached around on various fora and found reports of similar problems and various suggested solutions. One of the solutions was to switch the mouse off and remove the dongle from the laptop before booting. Then log in. The wait (at least) 10 seconds before switching on the mouse and plugging in the dongle.

This seems to work most of the time, but has failed to work at least once.

I have seen a posting (David Gatrell, 2012-06-23) to the effect that

"This is really more a duplicate of bug #958174, which is still open."

But as far as I can discern there has been no "activity" on this bug since the given date. And I'm not sure that this applies to Mint 13 (or only to "real" Ubuntu (12.04? 12.10?).

Has anyone any ideas as to how I can get reliable performance out of this cordless mouse?

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu 12.04 the mouse originally worked.  Then it became eratic. Then it began to work again. The mouse appears to be still erratic under Mint 13. I believe for Ubuntu, the problem was fixed by an update, likely linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic-pae 3.2.0-31.50.  Looking upstream at kernel.org, the release notes for kernel version 3.2.31 stable there is the following commit:

```
commit e189acb13e2dea021825975493d8e5222557df65
Author: Nestor Lopez Casado <nlopezcasad@logitech.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 21 12:21:34 2012 +0200

HID: Fix logitech-dj: missing Unifying device issue

commit 596264082f10dd4a567c43d4526b2f54ac5520bc upstream.

This patch fixes an issue introduced after commit 4ea5454203d991ec
("HID: Fix race condition between driver core and ll-driver").

After that commit, hid-core discards any incoming packet that arrives while
hid driver's probe function is being executed.

This broke the enumeration process of hid-logitech-dj, that must receive
control packets in-band with the mouse and keyboard packets. Discarding mouse
or keyboard data at the very begining is usually fine, but it is not the case
for control packets.

This patch forces a re-enumeration of the paired devices when a packet arrives
that comes from an unknown device.

Based on a patch originally written by Benjamin Tissoires.

Signed-off-by: Nestor Lopez Casado <nlopezcasad@logitech.com>
Signed-off-by: Jiri Kosina <jkosina@suse.cz>
Signed-off-by: Ben Hutchings <ben@decadent.org.uk>
```

It remains to be investigated whether Mint 13 has applied this patch or upgraded to this upstream kernel.